# How are the diameters of the cogs in a CVT mathematically related?

Tags: geometry

In a CVT (Continuously Variable Transmission) system, a belt is wound around two cogs that can change their diameters (to keep the post short, [here's how that works](http://www.cvt.co.nz/cvt_how_does_it_work.htm)). Suppose that the two cogs are a constant distance from one another and the length of the belt path must remain constant. What is a function that relates the diameter/radius of one cog to another?

[Here's a graph I made in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n9rsfi6yc3) to help visualize the problem. Another way to ask the question is: as I change the diameter of one cog, how should the diameter of the other cog change to keep the belt length (which is *L* in the Desmos graph) constant?

Comment: I agree with your formula for the belt length (when $r_1 > r_2$). With trig an non-trig functions mixed together that way I don't think there is a simple solution using standard functions. But you can get an arbitrarily good approximation numerically.

Comment: I think the following formula is a little less ambiguous: $L=2(\sqrt{d^2-(r_1-r_2)^2} + { \pi \over 2}(r_1+r_2)+(r_1-r_2) \arcsin {r_1-r_2 \over d})$.